# So good a time that vs a good time so

Tags: syntactic-analysis, semantics

Are the following two constructions synonymous?

◇ The guests had so good a time that they wouldn't leave.

◇ The guests had a good time, so they wouldn' leave.

Comment: They're quite different in structure, though they can describe the same circumstances. The first one is an example of the [_so/such `X` that `S`_ construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22so%2Fsuch%22+that), with very specific entailments, while the second one links two sentences and implies simple  causation.

Comment: @John Lawler: That means they are semantically the same.

Comment: No, it means they can be pragmatically the same. The semantics of the _so good a time that `S`_ construction entails direct causation, while the simple comma splice does not. Pragmatically, that may not matter, but semantically it does.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence suggests it was **unexpected** that the guests had a good time. I would expect it in a context similar to the following:

> I had to attend a birthday party at a retirement home with my college buddies (probably going to be boring).  However, we had so good a time that we didn't leave until 3 am.

But I would rewrite it as:

> The guests had **such a good** time that they wouldn't leave.

The second sentence is more neutral and doesn't suggest any surprise or tone from the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

While the sentences are almost identical, I do think each has a *slightly* different feel to it.

> The guests had *so good a time/such a good time* that they wouldn't leave.

I would say this is the more common construction of the two and carries a more playful connotation. In this case, the decision to stay appears more spontaneous and unplanned. They were enjoying themselves so much that it simply didn't cross their mind to leave. I would imagine this being said like

> "Sorry about my parents last night. They just had so good a time that they wouldn't leave!"

---

> The guests had a good time, so they wouldn't leave.

This is a less common construction. It seems to indicate that the "decision tree" of staying/leaving was known from the beginning and gives a slight feeling of rigidity. If the guests had a good time, they wouldn't leave. If they had a bad time, they wouldn't stay. Because they had a good time, they wouldn't leave.

Imagine this being said by a husband explaining to his wife why his friends stayed over so late the night prior:

> "Well, they had a good time...so (what would you expect? obviously...) they wouldn't leave."